# Two JS functions with Same name in single HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a  function. In which `data` get value from getValue() function.

Below code is a fragment.

**grid.js**

```
function gridLoadComplete(){
    var data = getValue();      
}
```

Consider below HTML's

- Index.html - Contains two below fragments

  - staffGrid.html
  - studentGrid.html

I have added `grid.js` fragment to **staffGrid.html** & **teacherGrid.html.**

When i load **index.html** it get's error. I don't get value in `data` because it's called twice.

Is there any way to resolve this problem. using the same function name `getvalue()` ??

---

Comment: So, you are trying to call `grindLoadComplete()` from index.html, but have it grid.js linked to staffGrid.html and teacherGrid.html, correct?  Try linking grid.js to index.html.  These are three separate files that won't share sources, unless you have it called by a fourth file where it combines the three (not with frames, that won't work).

Comment: I can't link `grid.js` to index.html. Bcoz getValue() function returns different values in  staffgrid & studentgrid.html

Comment: How have you included them as fragments?

Comment: The fact that they return different values should have any impact of including it.  What you have described is that you have three separate files, two of which are linked to the grid.js file while the third is where you need to call from.  Now you say that it displays different information in the staffGrid.html than the studentGrid.html, indicating you need it called from them, not index.html.  Perhaps you can explain how the three files are connected so we understand why you need to call the function from index.html instead of staffGrid.html and strudentGrid.html.

Comment: @coderboi_89 Tht's my part of mistake. I have corrected the question..

Comment: @AfilAnsari - Do you get the correct information displayed when you load the staffGrid.html and teacherGrid.html directly?  If not, you should look at the `getValue()` function instead of the `gridLoadComplete()` function.  Furthermore, the function you provided doesn't have any form of output, just the setting of the variable.

Comment: @coderboi_89 I'm able to getValue() for staffGrid.html but not for teacherGrid.html. Since same function already exists in page..

Comment: @AfilAnsari - How are both pages included in the index.html?  Are you using JavaScript to add the source to it, or is there a fourth file to combine the three?

Comment: @coderboi_89 I'm using `thymeleaf` fragment facility to add **.html** pages

Comment: @AfilAnsari - That explains much, however, there still shouldn't be a problem like this.  Now, you said that when you load staffGrid.html directly, not through index.html, it loads the data, but studentGrid.html does not, correct?  That means the function is doing what it's supposed to do for the staffGrid.html.  You need to look at the `getValue()` function to verify it is doing what it needs to when studentGrid.html is calling it.  It'd be a lot easier if there were more code to work with.  As it is, I recommend follow Hadi's example.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your issue rises from the fact that you have too many globals and that your code is not modular.

One solution would be to write your `grid.js` file in a way that's exposing a `Grid` component which can be instanciated and which encapsulates it's logic, so that the `index.html` page can create independent `Grid` component instances.

You can think of your grid or any UI component as re-usable components such as native `<select>` element.

What could you do with 2 select elements in the same page?

`index.html`

```
$(function () {
    var $select1 = $('#select-1'), //this could be staffGrid = new Grid('#staff-grid')
        $select2 = $('#select-2');

    //Make a parallel with the change event and your gridLoadComplete event.
    //gridLoadComplete should be fired by your grid component itself and your component
    //should allow to listen to those events.

    //It could be staffGrid.on('loadComplete', function () { staffGrid.getValue(); });
    $select1.change(function () {
        $select1.val(); //access select1 value
    });

    $select2.change(function () {
        $select2.val(); //access select2 value
    });
});
```

As you can see in the exemple above, we invoke the same `val` function to get the value, but against different instances which allows us to get the value we want without duplicating the `val` function's logic.

Comment: Thanks man.! Modular approach can solve my issue.. Good Day..!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider namespacing your javascript, such that each fragment has its own namespace. For example:

`staffGrid.html` would contain:

```
<script>
var staffGrid = {
    gridLoadComplete: function() {
        var data = getValue();
    },

    myOtherFunc: function() {
        //Do other stuff...
    }
};
</script>
```

Then in your `index.html`, you can call: `staffGrid.gridLoadComplete();` and `teacherGrid.gridLoadComplete();`

Comment: That doesn't solve the `getValue` issue. It would if `getValue` was added to your object literal, but then you would have duplicated logic across your grid files.